# Is there way to inject data to an exe file which stuck on recv call?

Tags: sockets, assembly, network-programming, code-injection, scapy

I'm researching some file in an academic homework setting.

I have an exe file - client.exe which connects to a server at known address and port, let’s say ip='1.2.3.4', port=1337.

At some point of the exe file, it sends some data to the server (of username and password that the user is input to the client), and then call the method `recv`, where the server returns "Welcome" if the username and the password were correctly, and "User not exists" Otherwise.

I saw that if we input to the client some special combination of characters, it's getting stuck on the `recv` function.

I sniffed the data, and saw that instead of getting PSH,ACK response from the server with the data ("Welcome/User doesn't exists"....) I'm getting in this case an ACK response only, without the data.

normal flow:
[image: normal flow]

special flow:

[image: special flow]

I wondering, if I can inject to the client opened socket the string "Welcome" by myself, using python, so it will not stuck on the recv function, think he got the "Welcome" from the server, and by that way, bypass the authentication of the program.

In order to do that, I used scapy, and faked a PSH response (not PSH,ACK since the server was ackked before), which have the same ip addr, port, and the correct sequence number of the packet, with the desired data. I send it when the client was freeze on the `recv`, I saw in wireshark that it's look ok (the packet was not colored in red or something like that) and I looked at the exe file, but it was still being stuck on the same `recv` call......

Am I doing something wrong?
Do someone have any ideas to what can I do in order to fake a packet from the server and bypass the authentication process? It can be with any other ideas, not only with scapy.

Thanks alot for any help.

Comment: It seems to me that ACK should always been set to 1 once the connection established. Quoting RFC793: *Acknowledgment Number: If the ACK control bit is set this field contains the value of the next sequence number the sender of the segment is expecting to receive.  Once a connection is established this is always sent.* I think the receiver expects this bit to be set in order to validate the received packet.